# Drag an SVG by using x and y attribute with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, svg, draggable

is it possible to make an SVG draggable by using the x and y attribute from the SVG?

is does not work with jquery draggable

```
$('#ninja').draggable({drag: function( event, ui ) {
   // $('#ninja').attr('x',ui.position.top+'%');
   // $('#ninja').attr('y',ui.position.left+'%');
}
});
```

Fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/n4d7gq3z/

Comment: `Rapheal.js` and  `snapsvg.io` are two library to manipulate SVG, but only within the SVG container.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, however if you look at an element inspector such as the one provided in Chrome developer tools, you'll notice that the path preceeding the end of your svg declarations:

```
<path transform="translate(-29 -22) scale(2.2)" opacity="0.25" fill=" #fff" d="M210.018,10.505H45.983c-19.599,0-35.487,15.889-35.487,35.487v69.409 c36.33,14.751,76.046,22.896,117.67,22.896c42.263,0,82.558-8.395,119.336-23.576V46.66 C245.504,26.394,229.615,10.505,210.018,10.505z"/>
```

Takes precedence over all the others, and overlays itself above all other svg elements and paths. If you remove this path or modify your styling or structure in such a way that it does not cause interference, your ninja svg draggable event fires and you can then commence processing.